# Stolz Cesàro's Theorem and sided limits

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> Does the limit of the function
> $\displaystyle f(x) = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\ln(2 + x) − x^{2n}\sin x}{1 +x^{2n}}$
> defined for $x > 0$ exist at $x=1$?
>
> Adapted from an [ISI entrance question](https://www.isical.ac.in/%7Eadmission/IsiAdmission2017/PreviousQuestion/BStat-BMath-UGA-2016.pdf)

I thought of using Stolz-Cesàro here: after appropriately indexing the sequences such that both sequences are strictly monotone, I take result:

$$ f(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\left[ \ln(2+x) - x^{2n+2} \sin x\right]- \left[ \ln(2+x) - x^{2n} \sin x\right]}{\left[ 1+ x^{2n+2}\right] - \left[ 1+x^{2n}\right]}= - \sin(x)$$

Seems so that limit exists at $x=1$ for $f(x)$

Now the intended solution goes in another way considering $(1+h)$ and $(1-h)$ and the limit $\lim_{h \to 0}$ for $f(x)$ (suppressing the limit over $n$)

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} f(1+h) = -\sin(1)$$

$$ \lim_{ h \to 0} f(1-h)= \ln(3)$$

The limit on $n$ though suppressed, doesn't matter because the final expression after we take the limit on $x$ first is independent of $n$

Question: why did I get the incorrect conclusion from Stolz?

Comment: You need to check the hypotheses of Stolz's theorem. One way to apply it, for example, is when $1+x^{2n}$ is monotone and tending to $\infty$. So, that case can work for $x>1$. However, for $x<1$ we have that $1+x^{2n}\to1$. So, this doesn't fit a direct application in of either case $\infty/\infty$ or $0/0$. The case $x<1$ can follows from the arithmetic properties of limit, since it is not one of the indeterminate cases.

Comment: Ah I see now , the monoticity changes depending on interval of $x$

Comment: @plop please adapt your comment into an answer, I'll gladly accept